# Regex in model rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

```
validates :version, format: { with: /\d+\.\d+/,message: "Version must be x.x format." }
```

this allow like `v 1.1` and `v 1.1.1`

but i want it allow only `1.1, 1.1.1, 1.2.3` etc, Only decimal and number i want to allow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
^\d.\d(\.\d)?$
```

Demo [here](http://rubular.com/r/dN6GKeScwD)

Answer (score -1):

Try This:

```
validates :version, format: { with: /^([\d\.]+)/,message: "Version must be x.x format." }
```

Comment: Can you please tell me where i went wrong for downvote.

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted, but generally people like to have an explanation with an answer